# replacing whole HTMLinside body tag

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the whole HTML inside **body** tag with some content and I use these codes inside both **head** and **body** sections, but in the fist code it doesn't show the content and in the second code it shows the content but doesn't clear ex-content.

the first code:

```
<script>

var content = 'some content';

if(navigator.appName=="Netscape")
{
document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML = content; 
}

</script>
```

the second code:

```
<script>

var content = 'some content';

if(navigator.appName=="Netscape")
{
document.body.innerHTML = content; 
}

</script>
```

also I use some php code in the document

what should I do?
thanks

Comment: Is this a joke? Are you writing code for extinct browsers, or what?

Comment: Looks like some W3Schools example code to me :)

Comment: Don't use browser detection at all; try to use feature detection instead.

Comment: what is the problem with the above code?

Comment: honestly, you shouldn't do anything, I don't think Netscape is used anymore.

Comment: Strangely , if I run navigator.appName in chrome , its output is Netscape

Comment: It's _always_ `Netscape`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appName

Answer (score 14):

`.getElementsByTagName` returns an array so you have to use `[0]` to get the first element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var content = 'some content';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = content; 

</script>
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MWjsc/

Comment: unfortunetly it's still the same

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you want to display some special content like browser not supported for netscape.

You can use [document.write](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) `document.write(content);` this will replace total document content.

Comment: no. i just don't want my site to display in some browser(e.g netscape) and give the viewer a warning message that he/she should use a different browser

Comment: in that case `navigator.appName` is not reliable. for example I am using Ubuntu 64bit / Google Chrome my `navigator.appname` is Netscape. so you have to look into `navigator.userAgent` for more information. for your need `document.write` will be the simple and best.

Answer (score 0):

Get fancy:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument().documentElement.outerHTML
// <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```